# Can't get an object from a get request

Tags: javascript, node.js, get

I can console log `userData.name` and `userData.summonerLevel` just fine, but why can't I `return userData` as an object?

I am trying to assign the returned object to a variable, but I really don't understand why it doesn't work.

```
function getStats() {
    https.get(https://euw1.api.riotgames.com/lol/summoner/v3/summoners/by-name/yojimbozx?api_key=${API_KEY}, 
    (res) => {
        let userData = ''

        res.on('data', (chunk) => {
            userData += chunk
        })

        res.on('end', () => {
            userData = JSON.parse(userData)
            if(!userData.hasOwnProperty('status')) {
                console.log(userData.name, userData.summonerLevel)
                return userData
            }
            return console.log("Summoner not found")
        })
    }).on("error", (err) => {
        return console.log("Error: " + err.message)
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can, but since you are doing some async stuff you should have your function getStats () return the http call and it should work. Currently you are returning the outcome of the call to the function, but the function is not returning anything